# how do I hide or encrypt query strings for gravity forms

Tags: forms

I am using gravity forms in wordpress and want to hide the query string from the user so they can't easily mess with it?

Whats the easiest way to do this without effecting the form, so auto populated fields still work

Comment: I found this solution, works well for what I need, just to slow down idiots that have half a clue......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58460638/hide-url-query-strings-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to reasonably and securely accomplish this with Gravity Forms' built-in features and the selection of AddOns currently available. So I have recently begun work on the **Gravity Forms Population Link AddOn** to provide more pre-population/prefill options and functionality. Among other things, it includes

- Encoding pre-populated values into a JWT token which cannot be reasonably modified by third-parties
- The option to disable pre-populated input fields
- An extra button to generate a pre-population link with a token, straight from the front-end form

I would love to have your input on the functionality!

In the near future I intend to encrypt the tokens by default to make them suitable for pre-populating sensitive data, and adding a second strategy to encrypt and store prefills in the database similar to how Gravity Forms handles it's "Save & Continue" feature.

https://github.com/bosconian-dynamics/gf-poplink